# Converting a str to a float (python34)

Tags: python, string, floating-point

There is a part in my python script where I recieve this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

code:

```
for proj in data['daily_projections']:
  proj['nba_player_id'] = float(proj['nba_player_id'])
  print(proj['fanduel_fp'] + ' ' + proj['nba_player_id'])
```

this what I currently have and it is not working properly.

'proj['fanduel_fp']' is the float and 'proj['nba_player_id']' is the string I need converted to a float

Comment: You probably want the opposite : convert to a string using `str` in order to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `proj['nba_player_id']`, `proj['fanduel_fp']` to string datatype while printing.

```
for proj in data['daily_projections']:
  proj['nba_player_id'] = float(proj['nba_player_id'])
  print(str(proj['fanduel_fp']) + ' ' + str(proj['nba_player_id']))
```

Comment: `proj['fanduel_fp']` needs to be converted too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which does not require explicit conversion:

```
print('{0[fanduel_fp]} {0[nba_player_id]}'.format(proj))
```

---

```
>>> proj = {'nba_player_id': '1', 'fanduel_fp': 2}
>>> '{0[fanduel_fp]} {0[nba_player_id]}'.format(proj)
'2 1'
```